# HTML form select: option attributes selected="selected" and default="default" not working

Tags: html, forms, select

I am using a simple dropdown box in HTML as below, with the first option (just a call-to-action) selected by default:

```
<select class="form-control" id="elementID" name="elementName" required="required">
<option value="" default="default" selected="selected">---Choose your Size---</option>
<option>25,000</option>
<option>50,000</option>
<option>100,000</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Send Now</button>
```

However, when the user selects one of the other options (e.g. 25,000) and refreshes the page instead of submitting the form, it continues to show that option selected. How do I prevent that? Using Firefox.

Tried to search for this problem but couldn't find it on SO. Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Unless your storing the new default value somewhere (i.e. server or localstorage), the browser (or the html code) will always default to what you built it as. I suspect you are writing all this in simple HTML.

Comment: Check the url at the top weather its showing the selected option  on submit. If its is than the form is working

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browser remembers what the user had input into the form when the page is reloaded, which is usually something very useful, for example if someone fills out a long form and then accidentally presses reload, or clicks a link. For this reason, I'm not really sure why you would want to disable this behaviour in the first place.

However, if it is necessary for you to do this, you could use the following javascript solution, which will execute upon loading the page and reset the dropdown to its default:

```js
document.getElementById("elementID").selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification. I thought I was making a mistake, leading to this behaviour. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off `autocomplete` attribrute on your wrapping form (if you have one) `<select>` tag. Like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
 . . .(your select tags and submit button)... 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the form is coming from Django and I'm not writing it myself in HTML. Let me figure out how to add this attribute to the form.